# How to run PHP script using more than one procesor

Tags: php, linux

I run a bash php script that uses one of four processors. The script compresses my pictures. Question now: how can I run my script to have the right to use 3 processors? It could definitely speed up the compression of all files, and there are about one million of them.

Comment: Doesn't the server itself divide the load between its processors? PHP is not multi-threaded.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard PHP itself is not **by default**. PHP enabled with `zts` (Zend Thread Safety) is well multi-threading. Together with `php-phtreads` it can work very well on multiple cpus.

Comment: To answer you question, you need to tell us HOW you compress. When you do something like `shell_exec("tar czf xxx.tar.gz ./backups/");` it is not PHP doing the work but `tar`. Multiple CPUs need multiple tasks. So you'd have to split the compressing itself into multiple tasks as it is only one task by nature.

Comment: i am using php script for not tar, i cut quality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run the same script on multiple processors because a script only has a single thread of execution.

If you partition the workload then you can run multiple instances of a script. The operating system will try to distribute these across the available CPUs. (You can force the processes to run a specific CPUs but its not worth the effort).

The trick is knowing how to partition the workload. The simplest solution would be to have a dispatcher process which assigns the input files to instances of the scripts and invokes those instances, e.g. by passing a list of files as a command line argument. Note that the method you choose for invoking the scripts needs to be non-blocking (e.g. using popen, NOT exec).

But for very large numbers of files in lots of locations, this could become cumbersome.

An alternative approach would be for the dispatcher to write the list of files to a database, and for instances of the script to read the queue for work:

```
$THIS_INSTANCE_ID=$argv[1];
$NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES=$argv[2];
$qry="SELECT filename
FROM conversions
WHERE MOD(id, ${NUMBER_OF_INSTANCES})=${THIS_INSTANCE_ID}
AND finished=false";
```

Comment: yes exacly, i do list all files which been compressed and then i do 3 parts and 3 scripts... thx

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use multiple cores is to run multiple threads or processes.

For web applications there is usually one PHP process per running script, so this is already the case: Multiple requests will use multiple cores automatically.

You can't use multiple cores for the same request though, but usually this doesn't matter for a web app.

Comment: I just think that I can use more procesors to increase speed,